# gitlab runner's scheduling is not as expected

Tags: shell, gitlab, runner

I set up two gitlab-runners on one device simultaneously，their tags are sh4hf and sh4fw.

```
gitlab-runner list
sh4hf                                               Executor=shell Token=MQ3***a5G_hmkbXhhc 
sh4fw                                               Executor=shell Token=-Ysa***_zxTr8nd27Cp
```

And I defined my ci pipeline as follows：

```
test:
  tags:
    - sh4fw
  script:
    - whoami
```

I have run the pipeline multiple times. But it sometimes seems to use another runner to execute the job
sometime

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.5.0 (0d4137b8)
  on sh4fw -YsaPMZz
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on ctrl04...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/hefeiqh/builds/-YsaPMZz/0/hefeiqh/test/.git/
Checking out ca86df76 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:00
$ whoami
hefeiqh
```

sometime

```
Running with gitlab-runner 15.5.0 (0d4137b8)
  on sh4fw -YsaPMZz
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:01
Running on ctrl04...
Getting source from Git repository
00:02
Fetching changes with git depth set to 20...
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /home/fw/builds/-YsaPMZz/0/hefeiqh/test/.git/
Checking out 8fd01431 as main...
Skipping Git submodules setup
Executing "step_script" stage of the job script
00:01
$ whoami
fw
```

but why?

thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

solved, its because i use one config.toml for multi runner

[image]

https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/faq/index.html